# 2008 Toyota Tacoma cabin air filter replacment

Tags: toyota, cabin-filter

What steps do I take to replace the cabin air filter on my 2008 Toyota Tacoma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will be located behind the glove box. Simple and straight forward.

[Check this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVwdwtVNvOU) for clear and detailed informations.

Answer (score 2):

Open your glovebox and release the shock on the right side. While holding the door portion, push the middle of the back of the box away from you and pull the whole box down. There should be a 1" X 6-8" panel with tabs on both sides, the right, or top. Remove the panel and you can remove the filter. Be careful not to let leaves or debris fall below into the blower.